# C++ takes forever to compile in VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to learn C++ but VSCode takes approximately 12 seconds to compile a basic print statement and in the terminal there's a giant list of something (I'm not quite sure what it is). I've run way longer Java code on VSCode before and it ran in >1 second so I'm relatively certain it's not because my device or internet is bad, can anyone tell me how to fix this

terminal:

```
PS C:\Users\student1\OneDrive\Desktop\Visual Studio Code\CPP>  & 'c:\Users\student1\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.18.5-win32-x64\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe' '--stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-kqxk2dli.p1n' '--stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-422e4goj.ifs' '--stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-yaf3e4kc.2kp' '--pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-dnljcjm4.zbs' '--dbgExe=C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\gdb.exe' '--interpreter=mi' 
hello world
```

Output:

```
[Running] cd "c:\Users\student1\OneDrive\Desktop\Visual Studio Code\CPP\" && g++ Variables.cpp -o Variables && "c:\Users\student1\OneDrive\Desktop\Visual Studio Code\CPP\"Variables
hello world
[Done] exited with code=0 in 12.275 seconds
```

Comment: *"giant list of something"* You mean your first snippet? Firstly I would compile outside of onedrive. Secondly I would try disabling the antivirus, if you have any. Also might be worth it to switch from `g++` to `clang++`, it's somewhat faster on Windows (but there shouldn't be a big difference for such small programs) (but IMO it's a better compiler in general).

Comment: Can you provide a (smallish) illustrative sample of what the "giant list of something" is.   If it is output of some messages to your terminal window, scroll up to the beginning (the last messages will be at the bottom, and the first messages are more likely to be representative of [part of] your problem).

Comment: Your antivirus may be the problem.

Comment: Since you are compiling and running all in one step there's no way to know if the compile process is taking a long time or if running the code is taking a long time. There's also the mystery of what's in the code that you did not share. Consider adding the code you're asking about and timing compilation and running separately from the command line to narrow it down.